# Mathematical induction proof I'm stuck on

Tags: induction

Use mathematical induction to show that $3^{3n} + 2^{n+2}$ is divisible by 5. Any help would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: Is it $3^{3n}$ and $2^{n+2}$? As you write the first term, it can be interpreted as $3^3n$.

Comment: Is this [homework](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question)?

Comment: test preparation

Comment: it's 3^(3n) thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you go all the time with modular arithmetic then

$$3^3=27=2\pmod5\implies 3^{3n}+2^{n+2}=2^n+2^2\cdot 2^n\pmod5=5\cdot 2^n=0\pmod5$$

and we don't actually need direct induction.

Comment: Well, the induction is in $a\equiv b\mod m\implies a^n\equiv b^n\mod m$ for each $n$, so it is there in disguise.

Comment: You're right, and that's why I wrote "direct"...

Answer (score 1):

First the base case.

Second: You assume that the statement is true for $n$ and you want to show that it hold for $n+1$. That is, you want to prove that $$3^{3(n+1)}+2^{(n+1)+2}$$ is divisible by $5$.

You are assuming that it holds for $n$, so that means: $5\mid 3^{3n}+2^{n+2}$. In particular, there exists an integer $q$ so that $5q=3^{3n}+2^{n+2}$. Solve for $2^{n+1}$ here and substitute on the first equation. You should be able to factor out a $5$ after you do some algebra.

Answer (score 0):

The main observation is that $3^3=27\equiv 2\pmod5$. Using this, the induction step goes like
$$3^{3(n+1)}+2^{(n+1)+2} = 3^3\cdot 3^{3n}\, +\, 2\cdot 2^{n+2}= \\
= (25+2)\cdot 3^{3n}+2\cdot 2^{n+2}=\dots $$
Then you can use the induction hypothesis (and that $5\mid 25$).